# Setting maximum width to 6 columns in bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using bootstrap to write heading in one line than paragraph information starting in next line.

```
   <div class="container col-sm-6">
        <h4>Daily Information</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6"></div>
    <div class="col-sm-6 cl6bg">
        <p>xyzzzzzz</p>
    </div>
```

Basically my goal is that Daily Information shows as heading than paragraph starts in next line. Since there are 12 col so it displays everything in same line. 
I tried to put empty div with col-sm-6 it didn't work. 
Please let me know how I can fix it so i can have them both in separate line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try using rows :

```
<div class="container">
  <div class='row'>
   <div class='col-sm-6'>
        <h4>Daily Information</h4>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class='row'>
    <div class="col-sm-6 cl6bg">
        <p>xyzzzzzz</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Maybe another **ugly** option could be using *col-md-offset-6* to force 12 cols...

Answer (score 0):

Add

```
<div class="clearfix"></div>
```

instead of that empty div.